# Resetting activity to original state when using the back button

Tags: java, android

When a user goes from activity A to B, then back to A using the back button, how do I reset the activity so it's in its original state?

Comment: I think that's not what @tomofv means by original state.

Comment: what do you mean by reset to original state ? explain more

Comment: He probably means the state just after onCreate(), by original state. So user never done anything yet.

Comment: By original state I mean what the activity would look like when it was originally started (e.g. opening the app for the first time).

Comment: Ok. Simply call `finish()` on Activity A after staring Activity B and in Activity B `onBAck,...` startActivity A again..

Comment: A better verb for that would be "restarting" instead of resetting, @tomofv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just finish your `Activity A` when you call `Activity B` and `onBackPressed()` of Activity B call it again . So it will start new `Activity A` .

Write below code in Activity B.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
     // Calling Activity A
     // Finish Activity B
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have `android:noHistory="true"` in your manifest file. A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the user will not be able to return to it. Find about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist).

Soon after yo have a back buton pressed at B you can have

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```